# How to handle Python datetime.replace overflow case?

Tags: python, datetime

I've got case when I should add an hour to datetime object and handle situation when such addition leads to day addition. E.g. it is 23:59 1st September, I add 1 hour and got 0:59 2nd September. Standard Python `replace` function doesn't handle such case and throws `ValueError`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 19, 20, 29, 850677)
>>> dt.replace(hour=dt.hour+10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

Of course I could write custom function which handles such situation, but I'd like to avoid it.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There we have to use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime.now()
dt2 = dt + timedelta(hours=10)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dt += datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
```